# sftp file browser client

Tags: php, flash, applet, sftp

I am looking for an stfp filebrowser, in either php, flash og as an java applet. I really dont wanna code this myself, since its really time consuming. So i was thinking if anyone know an opensource system that can do this. I know this can be very insecure, but i will only allow certain ips with certain passwords to use it.

Basicly what i want is some kind of filebrowser i can place on my webserver, so i can control the files on my server, witch is the same server i will host it on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is in php:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/